# How to access specific elements (by index) in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, multiplication

e.g. If I have 4 inputs `[I0, I1, I2, I3]` to a set of layers which produces 4 outputs `[O0, O1, O2, O3]`.

How would I add a `multiply` layer that multiplies specific individual elements, say [I1 x O3, I2 x O2, I0 x O1, I3 x O0]?

Comment: Tensors are basically fancy arrays, you should be able to do something like `tf.stack([input[1] * output[3], input[2] * output[2], input[0] * output[1], input[3] * output[0]])`